# display a toast at the beginning of a method

Tags: android, methods, show, toast

the problem is simple
I want to display a (message) toast placed at the beginning of a method to make wait

```
private void PartitionShow () {Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "wait processing ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show ();// the code of my method// ...}
```

only this message appears only at the end of the code of my method

a solution that works is to put the code in a class:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, String> {}
```

and manage the toast in:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate (Integer ... progress) {}
```

for those interested please see [sample code](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1745519/java/general-java/java-mobiles/android/afficher-toast-debut-d-methode/#post9581489)

only in my code I create objects and it gets heavy and slow to place it in another independent thread

thanks to those who will find me a much simpler solution?

Comment: What does "to make wait" mean?

Comment: Why don't you use a progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand.

```
private void PartitionShow () {Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "wait processing ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show ();// the code of my method// ...}
//// the code of my method//
```

will do some heavy task like writing a file or bulk data store or some heavy main thread operations. so you might face some glitch. you can do two things Introduce new `AsyncTask` or Use `Handler` for threading operations.